# Solving coupled differential equations involving the square of the derivative

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I want to solve the following system of coupled differential equations in order to obtain particle trajectories:
\begin{equation}    \frac{dt}{ds} = (E-y\, p_t)y    \end{equation}
\begin{equation}    \left( \frac{dy}{ds} \right)^2 = y^2 \left[ (E - y\,p_t)^2 - M^2 \right] \end{equation}
Where for simplicity, I set $p_t = 1$.

The objective is then to plot the solutions in a $t-y$ plane.

The code that I implemented is

```
    (*Solving numericaly*)

    $Assumptions = y \[Element] Reals
    
    E = 5;
    M = 1;
    pt = 1;

    sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[s] == y[s]*Sqrt[(E - pt*y[s])^2 - M^2], t'[s] == y[s]*(E - pt*y[s]), y[0] 
    == 3, t[0] == 10}, {y[s], t[s]}, {s, -100, 0.3}];
```

For the positive solution, and then copying and pasting this block with a negative sign in front of the `Sqrt` for the negative solution.

And then plot:

```
    ParametricPlot[{{ysol1[s], tsol1[s]}, {ysol2[s], tsol2[s]}}, {s, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> 
    {"y","t"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However I can't seem to get the expected solution for the trajectories of the particles, which is supposed to give something like this:

[[image: The vertical green line corresponds to <span class=]$y=0$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfZMU.png)

(the dashed circle isn't a part of the solution, only the hyperbolas and the vertical green line corresponds to $y=0$.)

With the code I described, I end up getting two hyperbolas, but they are both for $y>0$ and are facing the same side.

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm rather new to Mathematica and thank you for any help.

Comment: What initial data were used for solution 2?

Comment: Please pay attention that `E=Exp[1]` in the Mathematica. So use `E0=5` instead of `E=5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 branches in the analytical solution with variable `p=pt`,

```
E0 = 5;
M = 1;
sol = DSolve[{t'[y]^2 == (E0 - p*y)^2/((E0 - p*y)^2 - M^2), 
   t[3] == 10}, t, y]
(*{{t -> Function[{y}, (
    10 p + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[8 - 10 p + 3 p^2] - Sqrt[
     24 - 10 p y + p^2 y^2])/p]}, {t -> 
   Function[{y}, (
    10 p - Sqrt[3] Sqrt[8 - 10 p + 3 p^2] + Sqrt[
     24 - 10 p y + p^2 y^2])/p]}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[t[y] /. sol1], {y, -1, 10}, PlotLabel -> p], {p, 
  0.5, 2, .5}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Therefore, desired solution at `p=pt=2` looks like

```
Plot[Evaluate[t[y] /. sol1 /. p -> 2], {y, -1, 10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"y", "t"}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To plot it with circle and green line we use

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[t[y] /. sol1 /. p -> 2], {y, -1, 6}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"y", "t"}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Graphics[{Blue, Dashed, Circle[{2.5, 10}, .5], Green, Thick, 
   Line[{{0, 6}, {0, 14}}]}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I have one question, Initially I tried to solve like this by using the chain rule to substitute dt/ds for dt/dy * dy/ds, but when I showed this to my professor, he said I wasn't allowed to do this because t and y are independent coordinates so I can't differentiate t with respect to y. How come employing this method gives the correct result?

Comment: Actually you don't need any chain rule since from $dt/ds$ and $dy/ds$ we directly have $dt/dy=(dt/ds)/(dy/ds)$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll let you do the plotting. But these are not coupled ode's. The `y[s]` ode does not depend on `t[s]`. So you can solve that on its own, plugin in `y[s]` solution back into the `t[s]` ode's, then solve that on its own.

Second, these can be solved analytically. Also, `E` is `Exp[1]` so changed it to `e`. Also, when you took the sqrt of `y'[s]^2` by hand, you lost one solution. Finally, assumptions do not mean much with `DSolve`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
e = 5;
M = 1;
pt = 1;

ode1 = (y'[s])^2 == y[s]^2*((e - pt*y[s])^2 - M^2)
ode2 = t'[s] == y[s]*(e - pt*y[s])
ic1 = y[0] == 3
ic2 = t[0] == 10
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see the first ode does not depend on `t[s]`.

```
solY=DSolve[{ode1,ic1},y[s],s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For each one of the above solutions, there is a solution for `t[s]`

```
ode2=ode2/.solY
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can solve the above for `t[s]`

```
solT1 = DSolve[{First@ode2, ic2}, t[s], s]
solT2 = DSolve[{Last@ode2, ic2}, t[s], s]
```

So you have 4 solutions. 2 for `y[s]` and 2 for `t[s]`

I am not sure which pair you want to plot. But will leave that for you to decide.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up.
Upon plotting, it appears that both pairs of solutions lead to the same graph. However there seems to be a problem with the left hyperbola which gets cut off when it reaches $y=0$.